# Proving that $1 + \frac{r_2}{r_1} \ge \frac{1-e^{-(r_1+r_2)x}}{1-e^{-r_1x}} $

Tags: calculus, inequality

so, my problem is the following, I really tried everything I could...

Let $r_1,r_2 \in \mathbb{R_+}$ be two constants and let $f: x \rightarrow \mathbb{R_+}$, with $x\in \mathbb{R_+}$

Define:

$$ f(x) = \frac{1- e^{-(r_1 + r_2)x}}{1-e^{-r_1 x}} $$

I need to show that:

$$ 1 + r_2/r_1 \geq f(x) $$

For any $x\geq0$. I have no idea how to approach this... I tried differentiating, without success... Is it possible to prove this, analytically?

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Comment: Ok, I see what you meant: thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The inequality is equivalent to
$$
 \frac{e^{-r_1 x}-1}{r_1 x} \le \frac{e^{-(r_1+r_2) x}-1}{(r_1 +r_2)x}
$$
and that is true because the function
$$
 g(t) = \frac{e^{-t}-1}{t}
$$
is *increasing* on $\Bbb R_+$. You can verify this either by computing the derivative of $g$, or by interpreting $g(t)$ as the slope of a secant and using that $t \mapsto e^{-t}$ is *convex.*

Comment: Thanks, I'm so pissed I didn't see this by myself I actually want to punch the wall. I feel an idiot.

Answer (score 2):

*Alternative proof*:

It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{r_2}{r_1} \ge  \frac{1 - \mathrm{e}^{-(r_1 + r_2)x}}{1 - \mathrm{e}^{-r_1 x}} - 1
= \frac{1 - \mathrm{e}^{-r_2 x}}{\mathrm{e}^{r_1 x} - 1}$$
or
$$\frac{r_2}{r_1}(\mathrm{e}^{r_1 x} - 1) \ge 1 - \mathrm{e}^{-r_2 x}.$$

Using $\mathrm{e}^u \ge 1 + u$ for all $u\in \mathbb{R}$ (well-known, also easy to prove),
we have $\mathrm{e}^{r_1 x} - 1 \ge r_1 x$ and $1 - \mathrm{e}^{-r_2 x} \le r_2 x$. The desired result follows.

We are done.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint 1**: $$1+\frac{r_2}{r_1} \ge \frac{1-e^{-(r_1+r_2)x}}{1-e^{-r_1x}} \\\iff \\  (1+\frac{r_2}{r_1})(1-e^{-r_1x}) \ge 1-e^{-(r_1+r_2)x} \\ \iff \\  
(1+\frac{r_2}{r_1})(1-e^{-r_1x}) - (1-e^{-(r_1+r_2)x}) \ge 0$$

**Hint 2:** Apply differentiation.

Comment: Use the derivative test to check if the function is increasing on the interval of interest. I think that Martin R's answer above is more enlightening though.